# Pig does not import data into system before applying queries

Tags: apache-pig

I was reading some documentations on Pig Latin and could not fully understand why would Pig not need to import the data into the system before applying queries, during data analysis?
Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hadoop and HDFS there is a concept of Data Locality, which actually means that "Bringing your computer/code near to data" not bringing the data near to computer.

This concepts applied to all the data processing technology over Hadoop, like MapReduce, Hive and Pig.This is the mail reason Pig doesn't import the data into the system instead it goes near to data and analyze it.

**Data locality:** An important concept with HDFS and MapReduce, data locality can best be described as “bringing the compute to the data.” In other words, whenever you use a MapReduce program on a particular part of HDFS data, you always want to run that program on the node, or machine, that actually stores this data in HDFS. Doing so allows processes to be run much faster, since it prevents you from having to move large amounts of data around.

When a MapReduce job is submitted, part of what the JobTracker does is look to see which machines the blocks required for the task are located on. This is why, when the NameNode splits data files into blocks, each one is replicated three times: the first is stored on the same machine as the block, while the second and third are each stored on separate machines.

Storing the data across three machines thus gives you a much higher chance of achieving data locality, since it’s likely that at least one of the machines will be freed up enough to process the data stored at that particular location.

Reference: http://www.plottingsuccess.com/hadoop-101-important-terms-explained-0314/